# Default and custom constructor

Tags: c#, default-constructor

I have a simple question.

Assume that I have class like below.

```
    public class DamageToDeal
    {
        public bool enabled;
        public float value;
        public TDValue type;

        public DamageToDeal() { }

        public DamageToDeal(bool _enabled, float _value, TDValue _type)
        {
            enabled = _enabled;
            value = _value;
            type = _type;
        }

    }
```

I read that if I have custom constructor the default is not automaticaly generetared

Do I have to initialize fields myself with default values(0, null) or default constructor with empty body will do it anyway?

Or if the default constructor is initializing fields even if he has empty body ?

Comment: the fields are initialized to default values per default, so you don't need to

Comment: But I have to have this empty constructor yes ?

Comment: @Filus1025 Unless you have no other constructors, yes, you have to state it.

Comment: `TDValue` is the only thing you have to worry about. How about making a field initialization?

Comment: It´s enough when you have a constructor with params, no need for parameter-less ctor. All your values are initialized to their default-values (null for `TDValue`) anyway.

Comment: @Filus1025 if you want a parameterless constructor, then you need to specify it

Comment: Ok I understand it now thanks for replies.

Comment: I misread the post. I guessed that he didn't want a `default(TDValue)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory allocated to a new class instance is cleared by the memory allocator. You only have to ensure that any fields you want to have a non-default value is assigned.

This is documented here: [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Managed objects automatically get clean content to start with, so their constructors do not have to initialize every data field.

You do not need an empty parameterless constructor for this to happen. You would only add that constructor if you actually want to call it and that makes sense for the type.

Also note that any field declarations that also states an initialization expression is lifted into constructors.

If you do this:

```
public TDValue type = new TDValue();
```

then regardless of which constructor is called that field will have an instance reference to a new `TDValue` object.

---

Note that the above is valid for classes, not for structs. For structs you need to ensure you assign all fields because memory is not always "allocated", it might be just reserved on the stack.